# Making .htaccess rewrite all requests to /web with a front controller?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, silex

I'm trying to route all requests to `/web/index.php` (front controller) while serving static files directly if they exist.

The following `.htaccess file` was taken from a Symfony 2 application, and seems to work fine as it is. Requests are sent to `./index.php` and I can access to static files like `./web/css/style.css`. I'm working on a shared hosting (not a good one) and this `.htaccess` seems the only one working ([this](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html) will cause a 500 error).

How can I have route all requests to `/web` folder? It seems that I need to change something in `E=BASE` variable, I've tried `[E=BASE:%1/web]` but it doesn't work.

I have a little understanding of rewrite rules, can you point me to the right direction?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off here... but isn't it just: change the last line to:

```
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/web/index.php [L]
```

For the static files it needs to be looking in your /web folder to check if the file exists. Currently the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` just checks if the filepath requested exists.

Try throwing a RewriteBase command in before the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f:

```
RewriteBase /web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

Comment: Yes for the front controller to work, but not for static files; ie /css/style.css doesn't work while /web/css/style.css does.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your .htaccess with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^((?!web/).*)$ web/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your domain is **gremo_silex.com**, and your hosting has directory for it like

```
~/domains/gremo_silex.com/public_html
```

(all hosting services I used last few years had directory structure similar to this).
Then you can place your Silex project one directory up (in `~/domains/gremo_silex.com`) and rename your `web` directory to `public_html`, this way there's no `web` in your url's.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today. Normally the web host would allow you to change Apache's document root (my preferred method) but in this case it wasn't possible. So with some hackery I compiled this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Serve all public files from /web/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web/
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]

    # If file doesn't exist send to front controller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The `REQUEST_URI` header comes in to PHP without the `/web` prefix too, so routing should work out of the box.